# edit XML rootelement using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am new to XML. I use the following function to create an xml file.
I want change the code to add some more details to its root element.
you can refer to the attached picture for my purpose.

```
Function fnCreateXmlNew()


   Dim objDom As DOMDocument
   Dim objRootElem As IXMLDOMElement
   Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMElement
   Dim objMemberRel As IXMLDOMAttribute
   Dim objMemberName As IXMLDOMElement

   Set objDom = New DOMDocument

   objDom.appendChild objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone=""yes""")
      Set objRootElem = objDom.createElement("_XPXML")
   objDom.appendChild objRootElem




    XMLFileName = "C:\Users\SHIVAMAIN\Documents\xml\TEST.xml"


    Set ParentNode = objDom.SelectSingleNode("_XPXML")


    Set childNode = objDom.createElement("_FTrans")
    ParentNode.appendChild childNode

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Unit")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 2
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("UnitAmount")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 525.3
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("RefN")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 0
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Desc")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "ÈÇÈÊ ÝÇ˜ÊæÑ ÝÑæÔ1"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Cre")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 0
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Deb")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 3798385
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Det2")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "16/0002"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Det1")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "03/0654"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Acc")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "1/0/01/02"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set childNode = objDom.createElement("_FTrans")
    ParentNode.appendChild childNode


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Unit")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 2
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("UnitAmount")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 54.6
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("RefN")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 645000
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("ODesc")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 41970130298#
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Desc")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "ÈÇÈÊ ÝÇ˜ÊæÑ ÝÑæÔ"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Cre")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 352170
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Deb")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = 0
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Det2")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "03/0654"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute


    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Det1")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "09/1571"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute

    Set nodeAttribute = objDom.createAttribute("Acc")
    nodeAttribute.NodeValue = "4/0/00/01"
    childNode.setAttributeNode nodeAttribute






objDom.Save (XMLFileName)

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [`setAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754616(v%3Dvs.85)) property after creating root element. Fill in `...` accordingly in below example.

```vb
...
' ROOT ELEMENT
Set objRootElem = objDom.createElement("_XPXML") 

With objRootElem 
  .setAttribute "Desc", ""
  .setAttribute "AppId", "1" 
  .setAttribute "Ver", "802" 
  .setAttribute "Srv", "SHN_ACCSERVER" 
  .setAttribute "DBN", "_AccXP_SHN98" 
End With

objDom.appendChild objRootElem


' ROOT CHILD NODES
Set childNode = objDom.createElement("_FTrans")

With childNode 
  .setAttribute "Unit", "2"
  .setAttribute "UnitAmount", "54.6" 
  .setAttribute "RefN", "645000" 
  ...
End With

objRootElem.appendChild
...
```